# How to fix error message Hash sum mismatch error

Tags: linux-mint, hashsum

I recently upgraded my Linux Mint to Rafaela 17.2 and while I was tweaking a little bit the interface and installing some themes and icons, I found myself with this annoying error message:

> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch"

Comment: Not a solution, but are you sure that doesn't let you complete the update? That's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/685145)

Comment: @terdon My bad, it does let me complete updates. But when I run the "sudo apt-get update" command it always ends with the error message I described. I just want to remove that error message as it is starting to become annoying at least for me. I think I'll try the other suggestions provided.

Answer (score 2):

Running `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` (as root) fixes this error.

<sub>Credit to [Google and ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243249&s=304d3d8d78b98aabfe3d702f13417a01&p=13226485#post13226485)</sub>